# How to return value where condition is TRUE in R

Tags: r, function

I am learning R by writing a function that considers a number and returns its prime factors (see below).

```
prime<-function(x){
    {num<-x %% 2:(x-1) == 0
        }
    return(num)}
```

I get output of True or False but I am looking for the value of records that are True. For instance: if x=9, I will get its prime factor 3. I tried "num<-any(x %% 2:(x-1) == 0)" and "num<-which(x %% 2:(x-1) == 0)" but neither brings the desired result. Your suggestions would greatly help.

Comment: You could start a data structure, like a list, outside the method (maybe passing to it as a parameter) and every time the condition is true then you add the number to that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
num <- which(x %% 2(x - 1) == 0) + 1
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: thank you. I figured it out using something very similar but what you have also make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
prime<-function(x){
    seq <- 2:(x-1)
    num<-x %%  seq == 0
    seq[num]
}
prime(9)
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Very close to some of the other suggestions but unique still. Good luck RStudent!